# Knex.js with Joi binding

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, joi

I'm using Knex.js (along with Bookshelf.js) with a PostreSQL DB and I'm trying to "extract" the SQL schema in order to use it with something like [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) or [Checkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chekit).

Here just a simple example:
The schema written with knex:

```
return knex.schema.createTable('users', table => {
  table.string('username').notNullable()
  table.string('password')
})
```

And what I would like to automatically get:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  username: Joi.string().required(),
  password: Joi.string()
})
```

The point is simply to avoid writting the schema twice and having a programmatically way to validated the objects, before passing it to bookshelf/knex. Are there any built-ins ways to do it? Or any best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this manually or write your own schema builder which outputs Joi schema and knex migrations...

Usually people just make migrations separately in `knex` and then updates Joi validations to be in sync with changed DB schema.

Answer (score 0):

If people are looking for a similar service, than the one asked. I just released a library that converts a **Joi schema** into a **SQL table** with **Knex**.

https://github.com/Fantasim/joi-to-sql

For the moment, the library only supports MySQL and essential features of it, but I plan to add more like auto-migration (on MySQL).
If you need other features or other DB support, pull requests are welcomed!